# TLScontact Travel Document returned by courier

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I've applied to gov.uk website for standard visitor visa for 6 month to UK. I've provided my biometrics on tlscontact website(location - Helsinki). I've paid additinal 100 euro to keep my passport because I needed to travel before receiving decision.
When I'm tracking my application on tlscontact, "Passport picked by applicant" is red
[image]

The last email which I received from tlscontact was this:
[image]

The problem is that I haven't received any email or letter from DHL. As you can see in the email the waybill number is blank, so I can't track it from dhl. So how can I proceed with this problem?
I provided my biometrics on 2.12.2021

Comment: You say you kept your passport - that makes me wonder if it's possible the website simply isn't properly set up for this situation. The status seems to suggest you should be *collecting* your passport, which makes no sense if you still have your passport. Likewise, the email talks about your travel document (i.e. passport) being couriered to you, which both contradicts the idea you should be picking it up and also makes no sense if you still have your passport. Have you checked your application status on gov.uk?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to track the application directly from gov.uk as they suggest. I'm opening my application from gov.uk and then being redirected to tlscontact website(after clicking provide biometrics button) and that's where I'm able to track the application(first picture). I can't log in directly to tlscontact(without redirection from gov.uk) because they don't give credentials separately

Comment: ah, in that case unfortunately I can't help you. If I were in your position I'd contact TLS directly to ask for clarification, but perhaps somebody else here knows more than I do.

Comment: Hello @GiorgiSh, I am also in a similar situation. Can you please let me know what happened after this email ? . Did you submit your passport ?